# Simulating a time-inhomogeneous Poisson process using the thinning method and the NeuroTools python module

Tags: python, poisson

There are several threads asking for a way to simulate time-inhomogenous poisson processes in python. The NeuroTools module offer a simple way to do so via the inh_poisson_generator () function. The help of this function is introduced at the bottom of this thread. The function was originally designed to simulate spike trains, and uses the thinning method. 
I would like to simulate a spike train during 2000ms. The spike rate (in Hertz) changes every millisecond, and is comprised between 20 spikes/second and 160 spikes/second. I've tried to simulate this using the following code:

```
import NeuroTools
import numpy as np
from NeuroTools import stgen
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

st_gen = stgen.StGen()
time = np.arange(0, 2000)
t_rate = []
for i in range (2000):
    t_rate.append(random.randrange(20, 161, 1))
t_rate = np.array(t_rate)

Psim = st_gen.inh_poisson_generator(rate = t_rate, t = time, t_stop = 2000, array = True)
```

However, the code returns very few timestamps (e.g., array([  397.55345905,  1208.79804513,  1478.03525045,  1982.63643262]), which doesn't make sense to me. I would appreciate any help on this.

```
inh_poisson_generator(self, rate, t, t_stop, array=False) method of NeuroTools.stgen.StGen instance
Returns a SpikeTrain whose spikes are a realization of an inhomogeneous 
poisson process (dynamic rate). The implementation uses the thinning 
method, as presented in the references.

Inputs:
    rate   - an array of the rates (Hz) where rate[i] is active on interval 
             [t[i],t[i+1]]
    t      - an array specifying the time bins (in milliseconds) at which to 
             specify the rate
    t_stop - length of time to simulate process (in ms)
    array  - if True, a numpy array of sorted spikes is returned,
             rather than a SpikeList object.

Note:
    t_start=t[0]

References:

Eilif Muller, Lars Buesing, Johannes Schemmel, and Karlheinz Meier 
Spike-Frequency Adapting Neural Ensembles: Beyond Mean Adaptation and Renewal Theories
Neural Comput. 2007 19: 2958-3010.

Devroye, L. (1986). Non-uniform random variate generation. New York: Springer-Verlag.

Examples:
    >> time = arange(0,1000)
    >> stgen.inh_poisson_generator(time,sin(time), 1000)enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have an answer for you but because this post helped me to get started with NeuroTools, I thought I'd share my small example which is working fine.

For the inh_poisson_generator() the rate input is in unit Hz and all times are in ms. I use an average rate of 1.6 spikes/ms, so I expect to receive ~4000 events. The results confirm that just fine!

I guess it might be an issue that you are using a non-continuous rate. However I barely know anything about the algorithm implemented for this function..

I hope my example can help you somehow!

```
import NeuroTools
from NeuroTools import stgen
v0=1.6 #spikes/ms
Amp=1 # amplitude in spikes/ms
w=4/1000 # periodic frequency in spikes/ms
st_gen = stgen.StGen()
tstop=2500.0
intervals=np.arange(0,tstop,0.05)
rate=np.array([])
for tt in intervals:
    v_next=v0+Amp*math.sin(2*math.pi*w*tt)
    if (v_next>0.0):
            rate=np.append(rate,v_next*1000)
    else: rate=np.append(rate,0.0)
PSim=st_gen.inh_poisson_generator(rate=rate,t = intervals, t_stop = 2500.0, array = True) # important to have rate in Hz and all other times in ms
print len(PSim)
print np.mean(rate)/1000*tstop
```